# How to prevent Rails from cascading deletion on some relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following classes

```
class Market < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
 has_many :categories, through: :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :market
 belongs_to : category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
 has_many :markets, through: :products
end
```

Now with the following code:

```
market = .. #some market
market.categories.destroy_all
```

market products are deleted as well! How to prevent this ?

**Edit**
Categories don't get deleted in the first place, but only products! And using `market.categories.delete_all` only delete products in one query instead of many, but again categories aren't deleted! It seems this is the way rails handle this situation of relationships, to destroy products such that market isn't related to categories anymore, so it has the illusion of deleting them! And hence any destroy callback on category isn't called, as category isn't deleted!

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand the difference between [`delete_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class) and [`destroy_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class).

The first one will simply execute the SQL DELETE.

Docs on `delete_all`:

> Deletes the records matching conditions without instantiating the
>   records first, and hence not calling the destroy method nor invoking
>   callbacks. This is a single SQL DELETE statement that goes straight to
>   the database, much more efficient than destroy_all. Be careful with
>   relations though, in particular :dependent rules defined on
>   associations are not honored. Returns the number of rows affected.

From docs on `destroy_all`:

> Note: Instantiation, callback execution, and deletion of each record
>   can be time consuming when you’re removing many records at once. It
>   generates at least one SQL DELETE query per record (or possibly more,
>   to enforce your callbacks). If you want to delete many rows quickly,
>   without concern for their associations or callbacks, use delete_all
>   instead.

So to not execute callbacks you should resort to delete, not destroy. On the contrary, destroy is preferable when you have callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I need callbacks to run? Adding dependent: :nullify to has_many :products in category class doesn't do anything, as it seems deleting categories throw market doesn't consider this relationship.

Comment: After trying delete_all, it just deletes all products in one query, and categories aren't deleted!

Comment: @LoaiGhoraba To both of your comments there is an answer in what I posted. Just read carefully :)

Answer (score 0):

```
market = .. #some market
market.categories.delete_all
```

But deleting categories will raise problems for products records. The better way using `destroy_all` and in the `before_destroy` callback set `category_id = nil` for products.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but the call back doesn't get called ! Actually categories don't get deleted in the first place, but only products!

Answer (score 0):

```
market.categories.delete_all # delete instead of destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I know the answer: Category and Market are a many-to-many relation ship, so when you say `market.categories.delete_all` (or destroy_all) it tries to break the relation between this market and its categories, which means deleting the join records, which are produtcs records in our case.